# grep for single quote and double quote in a string

Tags: regex, shell, unix, grep

so i am trying to write a grep which finds the .epl file names or file paths in a given file.

I have tried the follwoing regexs

Part 1 : REGEX Used `grep -rEco "\/(.+)\.epl|(.+)\.epl" ./index.epl`
Result obtained

```
    url => 'xyz.epl
    url => 'xyz.epl
    url => 'xyz.epl
    url => "packet/xyz.epl
    url => "/web/abc/xyz.epl
    url => qq{/web/abc/xyz.epl
    url => '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    url => '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    url => 'xyz.epl
    url => 'xyz.epl
    $url = "/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    var requestURL = "xyz.epl
    var requestURL = "xyz.epl
    <a style="float:left;" href="xyz.epl
    [- Execute('components/xyz.epl
    Welcome, <a href="xyz.epl
    [- Execute('components/xyz.epl
    <a href="xyz.epl
    [- Execute(`'components/xyz.epl`
```

However I want it to match only the following(with or without the preceding quotes)

```
    'xyz.epl(OR xyz.epl)
    'xyz.epl
    'xyz.epl
    "packet/xyz.epl(OR packet/xyz.epl)
    "/web/abc/xyz.epl(OR "/web/abc/xyz.epl)
    /web/abc/xyz.epl
    '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    '/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    'xyz.epl
    'xyz.epl
    "/web/abc/def/xyz.epl
    "xyz.epl
    "xyz.epl
    "xyz.epl
    'components/xyz.epl
    "xyz.epl
    'components/xyz.epl
    "xyz.epl
    'components/xyz.epl
```

To obtain the desired out i tried `grep -rEoc '\/(.+)\.epl|[\"\'](.+)\.epl'`
However it gives me an  `unmatched '.` error

I removed the quotes surrounding the regex and I got 
`Badly placed ()'s.`

please help me in achieving the correct desired output.

Comment: Can you show sample of your original input data?

Comment: if you use option -o as argument it does not
`-o
--only-matching
Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines, with each such part on a separate output line.`

No i am sorry, I cannot due to confidentiality restrictions. I think the information provided is sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question trhough two separate sources.
One is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285450/grep-for-single-quote-and-double-quote-in-a-string) .
The other one was

```
set quote='"'; grep -E "\/(.+)\.epl|['${quote}](.+)\.epl" /index.epl
```

The set quote did the trick

Answer (score 0):

How about telling what characters are accepted as part of the filenames:

```
grep -Eo "[0-9a-zA-Z/]*.epl" ./index.epl
```

Comment: The `E` flag is unnecessary in this case (though it doesn't harm). A slightly safer way would be `grep '[0-9a-zA-z/]*[.]epl' index.epl` to ensure that there is indeed a period in front of epl. However, if there are the pattern could be *any* valid filename, this would not work, because nearly any character can be part of a file name.